# How to set text of combobox after setting SelectedValue

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox being databound from an sql stored procedure and I am trying to have the text change when I set the .SelectedValue to a different value but it does not change. Is there a way to make this behaviour occur?

the displayMember is set to Firstname and the ValueMember is set to an ID from a table and I am trying to change the text of the combobox programatically

cbo.SelectedValue  = 3 will set the selected value but not alter the text appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select in two ways, in example:

1) `cbo.SelectedItem = "C"` - for strings items

2) `cbo.SelectedIndex = 3` - for strings and numbers.

Note: SelectedIndex first item has index=0.

Comment: Yes I understand I can do it this way but lets say there is one value in this combobox but the valuemember assigned to it on databind is say 3, then I cannot specify cbo.selectedIndex = 3 as that would be out of bounds

Comment: If I use cbo.SelectedItem = "C" , will that in turn change the cbo.SelectedIndex as well ?

Comment: In example, C has index 2 (zero-based). If SelectedItem="C", SelectedIndex returns 2.